# Single App Kiosk Mode - Disable 'New Window' or Enable Full-Screen Chrome on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mdm, intune

Using Microsoft Intune MDM, I've configured an iOS iPad device into Single App Web Kiosk mode in Chrome. Currently, a 'New Window' option opens a non-closable Chrome split-screen due to Single App mode. Is there a way to either disable the "New Window" option or make Chrome launch in full-screen mode with no visible address bar and settings tab? Any assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried in Safari?  Unless you are using the Google user profile features of Chrome there is no benefit to using chrome on iOS. All browsers on iOS use WebKit as the web rendering engine.